# How do I preevnt an ion-checkbox from being checked when an icon in its row is clicked?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, checkbox, event-propagation, ionic7

I'm using Ionmic 7 with React 18.  I have this simple list of items that can be checked or edited.

```
<IonList>
  <IonLabel>
    <strong>Select Items</strong>
  </IonLabel>

  {items.map((item) => (
    <IonItem key={item}>
      <IonCheckbox
        slot="start"
        name="selectedItems"
        value={item}
      />
      <IonLabel>{item}</IonLabel>
      <IonIcon
        icon={pencilOutline}
        slot="end"
        onClick={onEditHandler(item)}
        style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }}
      />
    </IonItem>
  ))}
</IonList>
```

The problem is when I click on my "edit" icon (the pencil), the checkbox is being checked and my edit handler is not invoked.  The demo is here -- https://stackblitz.com/edit/an5yjh-i9tnnh?file=src%2FApp.tsx,src%2Fcomponents%2FFormWithChceckboxes.tsx.  I thought adding this to the handler

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

would prevent the checkbox from getting checked and the procedure could continue, but evidently not.

Comment: It looks like it's not only the pencil triggering the action, the whole container is "clickable" for some reason, as if the IonItem itself handles that click... 
When I remove the IonItem Component it works as expected, I suppose the alert that says "Editing Item x" is wanted?

Comment: Yes the alert is just for demo purposes, but you shoudl see it if you click on the pencil icon.  I tried removing the IonItema nd replacing it with an empty fragment, but then everything appears on the same row.  Also I no longer have a key for each row, although not sure how critical that is.  I need to read more about IonItem and its rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend that you use syntactically correct HTML by using a `button` to trigger an action

```html
  <IonButton fill="clear" onClick={() => onEditHandler(item)}>
    <IonIcon slot="icon-only" icon={pencilOutline}></IonIcon>
  </IonButton>
```

Like that you won't need to battle with the bubbling effect.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/an5yjh-b5wpv5?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FFormWithChceckboxes.tsx

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve the issue by adding a z-index to the edit icon to position it above the `IonItem` like this:

```
<IonIcon
  icon={pencilOutline}
  slot="end"
  onClick={onEditHandler(item)}
  style={{ marginLeft: '10px', zIndex:10 }}
/>
```